# Under the impression that these two SQL queries would give the same output, yet they have wildly different results

Tags: sql, pandas, grouping, pandasql

I am using `pandasql`. The first turns values as expected, but the second returns things that shouldn't even exist. However, I would expect them to return the same value. The only difference, to my eye, is that in the first one, the grouping/sum occurs within the subqueries, while it occurs outside of them in the second one. What am I missing? Thank you for the help! (Outputs at bottom)

First query (the correct one)

```
SELECT a.'Name', a.Q1, b.Q2, (a.Q1 + b.Q2) AS Total
FROM
    (SELECT c.'Name', SUM(c.'Paid Amount') AS Q1
     FROM some_data AS c
     WHERE c.'Quarter' = 'Q1'
     GROUP BY c.'Name') AS a
JOIN
    (SELECT d.'Name', SUM(d.'Paid Amount') AS Q2
     FROM some_data AS d
     WHERE d.'Quarter' = 'Q2'
     GROUP BY d.'Name') AS b
ON a.'Name' = b.'Name'
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Second query (the bad one)

```
SELECT a.'Name' as Label, SUM(a.'Paid Amount') AS Q1, SUM(b.'Paid Amount') AS Q2, (SUM(a.'Paid Amount') + SUM(b.'Paid Amount')) as Total
FROM 
    (SELECT c.'Name', c.'Paid Amount'
     FROM some_data AS c
     WHERE c.'Quarter' = 'Q1') AS a
JOIN
    (SELECT c.'Name', c.'Paid Amount'
     FROM some_data AS c
     WHERE c.'Quarter' = 'Q2') AS b
ON a.'Name' = b.'Name'
GROUP BY Label
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

I threw some random data together to demonstrate the problem.

Output from the first query (expected)

[image: Output from the first query (expected)]

Output from second query (problematic)

[image: Output from second query (problematic)]

Comment: Does `a.'Name' = b.'Name'` work in any database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I call wishful coding.

I hope you realize that doing the aggregation *before* joining produces the correct answer.

The issue is that `JOIN` can both multiply the number of rows and remove rows.  In your case, the issue is that one or both tables have multiple rows for `name` and this multiplies the number of rows.  The `SUM()` just adds up all the values produced as a results of the `JOIN`.

Note:  Conditional aggregation is a much simpler way to write the query:

```
SELECT c.Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.Quarter = 'Q1' THEN c.PaidAmount END) AS Q1
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.Quarter = 'Q2' THEN c.PaidAmount END) AS Q2
FROM some_data AS c
WHERE c.Quarter IN ('Q1', 'Q2')
GROUP BY c.Name
```